# Problema con llamada a procedimiento almacenado mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedure

Tengo un problema a la hora de llamar varias veces seguidas (dentro de un while) a un procedimiento (con el CALL nombreProcedimiento(parametro)) desde php en mi web.

Este es el código del procedimiento:

```
BEGIN
SELECT 
   @estado := estade,
   @subestado := subestado
FROM
   tabla1 
WHERE boletin = boletn; #(el "boletn" es el parametro que paso al procedimiento)

CASE @estado 
    WHEN 'estado1' THEN

        CASE @subestado
            WHEN '' THEN
                SET @tipo = 'Pendiente';

            ELSE
                SET @tipo = 'Sin identificar';
        END CASE;
END CASE;

UPDATE tabla1 SET tipo = @tipo WHERE boletin=boletn;
```

Y luego en php tengo lo siguiente:

```
$instruccion0 = "SELECT boletin FROM tabla1 ORDER BY fechaCarga DESC LIMIT 4";
$resultado0 = mysql_query($instruccion0, $conexion);

while($fila0 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado0)){

    $boletin = $fila0['boletin'];

    $resultado1 = mysql_query("CALL establecerTipoBoletin('$boletin')", $conexion) or die ("Fallo en el CALL procedimiento. Error: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Y aquí es donde viene el problema. Claro, yo lo que necesito es que a los 4 boletines que hay en la tabla (poniendo que hay 4), se ejecute el procedimiento, es decir, hacer un call cada vez a un boletín distinto, por eso lo del `while` en php. Pero cuando hago la acción (que el código php se "ejecuta" al pulsar un botón) me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Fallo en el CALL procedimiento. Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

En teoría ese error se debe a que se están realizando los CALLS al mismo tiempo, pero según lo que se de programación, entra al while, se ejecuta un call a un boletin, vuelve a entrar al while, ejecuta el call al otro boletin...

Nota: Si lo hago con 1 solo boletín (cambiando el 1 por el 4 en `"SELECT boletin FROM tabla1 ORDER BY fechaCarga DESC LIMIT 4";`) si que me lo hace correctamente y no me muestra el error (ja que logicamente solo entra 1 vez al while).

¿Alguien sabe porqué ese mensaje de error?

**EDITADO:**

He comprobado que salta el mismo mensaje de error si ejectuto 2 veces seguidas el mismo procedimiento, es decir, si hago dos veces el `CALL`. Si hago esto:

`$resultado1 = mysql_query("CALL establecerTipoBoletin('boletin1')", $conexion);
$resultado1 = mysql_query("CALL establecerTipoBoletin('boletin2')", $conexion);`

Salta el mismo mensaje de error.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Traducción de [la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818406/1983854) a la pregunta [PHP Commands Out of Sync error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14554517/1983854)</sub>

Para aquellos de ustedes que hacen lo correcto y usan procedimientos almacenados con declaraciones preparadas.

Por alguna razón, mysqli no puede liberar los recursos cuando usa una variable de salida como parámetro en el proceso almacenado. Para solucionar esto, simplemente devuelva un conjunto de registros dentro del cuerpo del procedimiento en lugar de almacenar el valor en una variable / parámetro de salida.

Por ejemplo, en lugar de tener SET outputVar = LAST_INSERT_ID (); puede tener SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID (); Luego en PHP obtengo el valor devuelto así:

```
$query= "CALL mysp_Insert_SomeData(?,?)"; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); 
$stmt->bind_param("is", $input_param_1, $input_param_2); 
$stmt->execute() or trigger_error($mysqli->error); // trigger_error here is just for troubleshooting, remove when productionizing the code
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($output_value);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->next_result();
echo $output_value;
```

Ahora está listo para ejecutar un segundo procedimiento almacenado sin tener el error "Comandos no sincronizados, no puede ejecutar el comando ahora". Si devolvió más de un valor en el conjunto de registros, puede recorrerlos y buscarlos de esta manera:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $output_value;
}
```

Si está devolviendo más de un conjunto de registros desde el proceso almacenado (tiene múltiples selecciones), entonces asegúrese de pasar por todos esos conjuntos de registros usando

```
 $stmt->next_result();
```

Ademas en la doc oficial de php ya hay una solución a este problema:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#102904

Comment: ¿De qué pregunta-respuesta de [so] exactamente lo has traducido?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554517/php-commands-out-of-sync-error/14561774#14561774